# AxiosError: socket hang up on many posts requests send

Tags: node.js, sockets, axios, proxy, https-proxy-agent

> AxiosError: socket hang up.

I searched for this error, and I believe its because my server is overloaded.

```
server.on("connection", async socket => {
socket.on("message", async msg => {
    const data = await sendRequestWithProxy(msg.proxy)
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(data))
}
})
```

I usually execute this function on a Python script that works with threads. After like 5k requests with proxies I think my system overloads and cannot send any more requests and this is why I got the error. I do not overload socket connections, I connect only once per thread, and my threads is not over 2000.

```
const sendRequestWithProxy = async (proxy) => {
const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0",
}
const res = axios.get("https://www.google.com", {
    headers,
    httpsAgent: new HttpsProxyAgent(module.exports.ParseProxy(proxy), { keepAlive: true 
}),
    httpAgent: new HttpProxyAgent(module.exports.ParseProxy(proxy), { keepAlive: true 
}),
}).catch(e => null);

if (!res) {
    return false;
}
return res.data;
}
```

I already tried putting a timeout on it and still not working, I got an error because the timeout excedeed.

How can I offload my system after an amount of requests?

Comment: Don't you need to close the socket after sending the data? eg. `client.send(message, (err) => client.close())`

Comment: no, i think, becase im using the same sockets, like if i have in python script 5k threads, only 5k sockets will be opened.